# Rails Logging with MongoDB - Can't Run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, logging

Good evening,

I'm trying to use the 'central_logger' gem to keep logs in MongoDB on my Heroku app.

I have done:

```
gem 'central_logger'  # gemfile
include CentralLogger::Filter  # application controller
```

I have installed MongoDB on my local machine (Mac OS X) via homebrew.  I can get into the mongo command line tool.

I get the following error when firing up the application:

```
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/central_logger-0.3.3/lib/central_logger/railtie.rb:12:in `block in <class:Railtie>': undefined method `log' for #<Rails::Paths::Root:0x007fa536f1d550> (NoMethodError)
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Also, when firing up the app via foreman, I'm assuming I don't have to load up a mongo process (it will just connect to the database itself same as Postgres I assume?)

Thanks!

Comment: Rails 3 or 2? Did you include "include CentralLogger::Filter" in your application controller?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tyler.  Yes - I have that include statement in teh application controller.  I am using the newest version of rails (3.2.6) with Ruby 1.9.3-p19(4?).  I confirmed that Mongo is working on my computer (I can write and read from a collection) - installed via Homebrew.

Comment: Hey Brandon, you still having trouble with this?

Comment: Hi Tyler.  I actually ended up going with MongoDB logger and got that running.  Thanks for following up though!